# what's easier: approximate a lognormal distribution with a normal distribution or the reverse?

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, mixed-model, lognormal-distribution

I am interested in understanding which of the following situations will be better approximated by this hypothetical model.

1. Simulate a dataset where one of a model's random (or mixed) parameters is normal $(\beta\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma))$. Then try to approximate the distribution of this parameter (incorrectly) specifying a lognormal distribution for this random (or mixed) parameter (i.e., estimating a model where: $\beta\sim\exp\left(\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma)\right)$)
2. The reverse case. (i.e., the true distribution is lognormal, but the modeler specifies this parameter as normal)

Intuitively, I think the model in the first case will better approximate the true distribution compared to the second one because. This is primarily because it seems easier to approximate a lognormal distribution (a bounded distribution) with a normal distribution (unbounded distribution) than the reverse case. However, I am having a hard time proposing a formal argument to sustain the stated claim.

**Edit**: I mean *"better"* in the sense that: "the larger the area of the intersection between the true distribution and the approximation, the *better*".

Comment: Great question. But keep in mind that there's another important difference, aside from the support of the distributions: the lognormal has heavier tails. Depending on what approximation criterion you're considering, this could be an argument that it's actually 2.

Comment: In what sense do you use the term "better"??  How can we measure or recognize when one such approximation might be preferred to another?

Comment: That's an excellent question, @whuber. Thanks for that. I just edited the question

Comment: I can't grasp what your idea is with this question. What if the parameter $\beta$ is distributed as a negative values, say $N(-10,1)$, then there's no way that a lognormal distribution is gonna be a good approximation. So possibly you are thinking about a specific case where this is no issue.

Comment: What do you mean by 'easier'? Like, related to the number of computations that you need to perform?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @SextusEmpiricus. I mean 'easier' in the sense that, in which case, (1 or 2) will have better coverage over the true distribution. If we think about a Monte Carlo simulation, say we run both scenarios 100000 times, and then we recover the overlapping with the true distribution (assuming positive support, thank you for that), which of the two would expect to perform better on this metric? I suspect that normal distribution approximates better a lognormal distribution than the reverse, but I cannot find a formal argument for this.

Comment: "Overlapping" is a symmetric concept.  This makes it hard to determine what you're referring to.  Could you tell us what you mean by "area of intersection" of two distributions?

Comment: @whuber, with that, I mean how much of the true density the approximation is able to cover.

Comment: @TTT when an approximate density covers a certain percentage of a true density, then the same is true when you switch the roles and that true density covers the same percentage of the approximate density. So if a certain normal distribution can cover x% of some log-normal distribution then the other way around the log-normal distribution can cover x% of a certain normal distribution. So how do you differentiate between the two? ...

Comment: ... Certainly, there might be normal distributions that are difficult to approximate with a log-normal distribution and there might be log-normal distributions that are difficult to approximate with a normal distribution. But you need to help us understand what the apples and oranges are and how you want to compare them.

Comment: I think this is well-posed. The similarity of two distributions with pdfs $f$ and $g$ is measured as $\int \min(f,g)$. Then: for a given lognormal, how similar is the most similar normal? And for a given normal, how similar is the most similar lognornal? And for distributions in reasonable ranges, which one of these values is higher?